# Displaying images on android widgets using html & TextView

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to display images dynamically on a home screen widget. As RemoveViews offer a very limited set of methods to interact with the layout, I'm trying to use HTML to get the same effect. 
Regular HTML displays ok (`<u>,<b>` etc) however I can't get images to display. Instead I get a little empty square appear in the TextView.

E.g.

```
s = "<b>Hello</b> <img src='world'/>";
ImageGetter imgGetter = new ImageGetter(context);
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
views.setTextViewText(R.id.textarea, Html.fromHtml(s, imgGetter, null));
```

The image getter looks like the following:

```
public class ImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter
{
    Context c;

    public ImageGetter(Context c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Drawable d = null;
        int resID = c.getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable", c.getPackageName());

        d = c.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(resID);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());

        return d;
    }
}
```

The code works fine if I am using a regular Activity. I suspect that this is a bug/undocumented feature of android when used with a AppWidgetProvider. I just want some confirmation.

Comment: I can confirm. It doesn't show images when used inside RemoteViews

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to display images
>   dynamically on a home screen widget.

Use `ImageView`. Update the app widget when you wish to change the image.